# Mapkit JS can't move map on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, maps, mapkit, coordinates, apple-maps

I'm trying use Mapkit JS for map. The code I have works fine on desktop. However, there is one problem when test it on a mobile phone. It seems that I cannot move the map around using my finger. On the desktop, I can move around the map with my mouse.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js"></script>

    <style>
    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 400px;
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
    mapkit.init({
        authorizationCallback: function(done) {
            done("API KEY");
        },
        language: "en"
    });

   var map = new mapkit.Map('map', {
   showsMapTypeControl: false,
   showsCompass: mapkit.FeatureVisibility.Hidden
    })

   var coordinateRegion = new mapkit.CoordinateRegion(
        new mapkit.Coordinate(40.51415196691954, -74.43808765761719),
        new mapkit.CoordinateSpan(1.234, 1.23423)
    );
   map.region = coordinateRegion;

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I copied your code exactly and it does allow me to move the map, at least on an iPhone 8. The only part that I changed is the API key retrieval, because I use a short-lived key. My code for that part reads: `mapkit.init({ authorizationCallback: function(done) { var x=new XMLHttpRequest(); x.open("GET", "getToken.php"); x.addEventListener("load", function() { done(this.responseText); }); xhr.send(); } });`

Comment: I have the same problem on an android phone.

Answer (score 1):

Mapkit JS versions occasionally have trouble recognizing touches from Android phones. You can test this in the Chrome developer panel. The fix is to change the version you are using.

As of the time of this writing, 5.19.x is the latest version that supports Android and 5.20.0 currently does not.

Comment: I found the same and also locked the version to 5.19.x.

Comment: Does this version still work for you? I tried almost all versions and I can't move the map on Android in any version right now. Web + iOS works well.